# Hide/show self based on radio checkbox

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website where I can only use HTML and CSS (no script). The platform is Squarespace, and they make it really difficult for you to work with code, but I have to make do. Also, they use a LESS preprocessor for styles.

I have 3 divs, with a full-size label in them, and then an svg code and text (I made the label full-size so that whenever these divs are clicked, stuff happens).

When you click on any of the 3 divs, they're all disappearing, and the 4th div with the "return" link appears. When you click on the "return", the other divs are supposed to reappear, and the "return" hides. However, even though the "return" hides, the other boxes do not appear.

I need the flexbox properties for styling.

```css
.resource-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
}

.resource-block-label {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.resource-return-label {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.resource-block-input:checked~.resource-return-label {
  display: block;
}

.resource-block-input:checked~.resource-block {
  display: none;
}

.resource-return-input:checked~.resource-block {
  display: flex;
}

.resource-return-input:checked~.resource-return-label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="resource-block" type="radio" id="rb-0" class="resource-block-input" />
  <div class="resource-block">
    <div class="resource-block-content">
      <label for="rb-0" class="resource-block-label">
                <svg>[svg code code]
                </svg>
                <span>1</span>
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input name="resource-block" type="radio" id="rb-1" class="resource-block-input" />
  <div class="resource-block">
    <div class="resource-block-content">
      <label for="rb-1" class="resource-block-label">
                <svg>[svg code code]
                </svg>
                <span>2</span>
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input name="resource-block" type="radio" id="rb-2" class="resource-block-input" />
  <div class="resource-block">
    <div class="resource-block-content">
      <label for="rb-2" class="resource-block-label">
                <svg>[svg code code]
                </svg>
                <span>3</span>
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input name="resource-return" type="radio" id="rb-return" class="resource-return-input">
  <label for="rb-return" class="resource-return-label">&lt Return</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Squarespace website is particularly stiff when it comes to editing code with html or css since they already have so much of their own custom code. Experiment with the !important property in css. This property overrides the css properties that Squarespace applies to their elements. If you more questions, you can ask on the Squarespace forum since they specialize in this area. Although, if you have the chance to test, I would recommend Webflow. It is similar to Squarespace in the way that you don’t really need to code, but you can add custom code and be a lot more creative with it.

Comment: I know the limitations of sqsp, and I hate them, but I absolutely have to work with it. !important does not work at all. This is a problem with my code somehow, not sqsp's. Since the initial show/hide works correctly, this one should too. But I'm thinking maybe there's a limitation based on how I format my css (what comes last should have priority).

Answer (score -1):

The `name=resource-return` to `name=resource-block` in the return button so that the all radio inputs are related. Also, I just wanted to know why you are not allowed to use scripting or javascript since Squarespace allows javascript.

```css
.resource-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
}

.resource-block-label {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.resource-return-label {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.resource-block-input:checked~.resource-return-label {
  display: block;
}

.resource-block-input:checked~.resource-block {
  display: none;
}

.resource-return-input:checked~.resource-block {
  display: flex;
}

.resource-return-input:checked~.resource-return-label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <input name="resource-block" type="radio" id="rb-0" class="resource-block-input" />
    <div class="resource-block">
      <div class="resource-block-content">
        <label for="rb-0" class="resource-block-label">
                  <svg>[svg code code]
                  </svg>
                  <span>1</span>
              </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input name="resource-block" type="radio" id="rb-1" class="resource-block-input" />
    <div class="resource-block">
      <div class="resource-block-content">
        <label for="rb-1" class="resource-block-label">
                  <svg>[svg code code]
                  </svg>
                  <span>2</span>
              </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input name="resource-block" type="radio" id="rb-2" class="resource-block-input" />
    <div class="resource-block">
      <div class="resource-block-content">
        <label for="rb-2" class="resource-block-label">
                  <svg>[svg code code]
                  </svg>
                  <span>3</span>
              </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input name="resource-block" type="radio" id="rb-return" class="resource-return-input">
    <label for="rb-return" class="resource-return-label">&lt Return</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Because you need to upgrade your plan and I'm on board a project with rigid requirements and supplied services.